# jmeter Reading Json data from file using JSR223, converting braces to square bracketconverting

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am using jmeter 5.1 in windows 10, in my jmeter test plan i am reading json data from file, after reading, i am using log.info ${sdata} to log the messages, but the output is converted the braces { to square bracket [, could someone tell me what's wrong.

Below is the data which the json file contains

```
{"name":"Foo Bar","year":"2018","timestamp":"2018-03-08T00:00:00","tags":["person","employee"],"grade":3.14}

{
    "name": "Foo Bar",
    "year": "2018",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-08T00:00:00",
    "tags": [
        "person",
        "employee"
    ],
    "grade": 3.14
}
```

Below is the line which i have in JSR223 Prepocessor to read the file and log it in info

```
def sdata = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new File("data.json").text)
log.info "$sdata"
```

And below is the output of log.info

```
["name":"Foo Bar","year":"2018","timestamp":"2018-03-08T00:00:00","tags":["person","employee"],"grade":3.14]

[
    "name": "Foo Bar",
    "year": "2018",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-08T00:00:00",
    "tags": [
        "person",
        "employee"
    ],
    "grade": 3.14
]
```

In the above output, the braces { got replaced to square bracket [

Please help

Comment: You have more than one JSON inside file

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're basically printing a textual representation of [LazyMap](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html)

If you want to see the same JSON as in the input you should create a [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class instance and pass the "slurped" object to it.

Change this line:

```
log.info "$sdata"
```

to this one:

```
log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(sdata).toPrettyString())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: it works, thanks for sharing me the solution. This one works for me JsonBuilder(sdata).toPrettyString())